# Can I run an offline graph processing algo on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, titan

Currently we have a table of followers on dynamo. (user_id, follows_who_id, date). We back it up in S3 and when we want to do heavy data processing we run EMR on the S3 files.

Now I need to make friends recommendations. This is more a graph job than a map reduce job. I can use the S3 files as an input (edges/vertices are natural from the data), but what tool do I use after ?

I found blog posts about Titan etc but it seems they work for queries (more or less like dynamo queries) but not for big batch processing.